# Android SL4A query

Tags: android, python, sl4a

How do I download zipped files containing python source code into the android SL4A ? I've tried going to the website and downloading it but the download always fails. Also can I install python-urwid in android?

Answer (score 1):

Go to here throuh your Android device browser:
 http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting

after you download the python*.apk file you click on it, then Open --> Install and it should be installed.
in case you have a problem to download it you can download it to your desktop machine then copy it to your computer.

as far as i know about urwid, you can't install.it on the SL4A.

Answer (score 1):

you can unzip file and send script files using the below command on command prompt.

```
adb push yourlocalfile.py /sdcar/sl4a/scripts/filenamepy
```

make sure you run this command

`adb devices` it will display the list of devices connected to the computer. If you see your device then you can run the above push command.
 Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a file explorer (I used andexplorer) to transfer the files to sl4a's install dir (ideally in a subdirectory), and unzip them there.

Comment: Hi. I am using the DDMS in Eclipse. I am able to push the zipped files but when I go back and check in my SL4A scripts it does not appear... I m not sure if it shows anything other than scripts...